# Initialize obj then pass into a function <bad ptr>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to initialize the values of an object, then pass it into a function, but visual studio tells me at this point that my two variables (question and answer) inside my object have "bad pointers" and cannot be evaluated. Unfortunately, I need to access both later on.

I've tried displaying question[i] and answer[i] right before calling enqueue() and it echoes correctly.

It's as if when I call the enqueue() function it doesn't remember what values I gave the card object when I called the constructor right before.

I'm not sure why my code breaks here, do I need to make a dynamic object?

```
card::card(char *q_input, char *a_input)
{
    char * question = new char [75];
    char * answer = new char [25];

    strncpy(question,q_input,strlen(q_input)+1); 
    strncpy(answer,a_input,strlen(a_input)+1);
}
```

...

```
int queue::fill_deck(char **question, char **answer)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        card Card(question[i],answer[i]);
        enqueue(Card); //ERROR!
    }

return 0;
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Please let me know if you need more information.

EDIT: the problem was that I was redeclaring two variables with my constructor. A syntax mistake on my part!

Comment: How was `card::card()` implemented?

Comment: @timrau I just added card::card() to the op.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Updated to show enqueue() definition.

Comment: In the `card` constructor, you don't seem to save `question` and `answer` anywhere. If those are just local variables, your code has no effect in the card object.

Comment: @glampert In my card class I define char *question and char *answer as private variables. I assumed I was changing those variables with the constructor, is this incorrect?

Comment: Nope, you are redeclaring new variables. When you prefix name with a type, e.g. `char * question`, you are declaring a new variable.

Comment: Well, that seemed to be the issue I was having - thank you! I took out the char * part in the constructor and the rest of it works.

Answer (score 1):

One huge issue:  This code does nothing except cause a memory leak:

```
card::card(char *q_input, char *a_input)
{
    char * question = new char [75];
    char * answer = new char [25];
    strncpy(question,q_input,strlen(q_input)+1);
    strncpy(answer,a_input,strlen(a_input)+1);
}
```

`question` and `answer` are local variables.  Not only that, you then allocate memory and assign the returned pointer to these local variables.  When that function exits, those locals go away, plus any chance of deallocating the memory you allocated goes away with it, causing a memory leak.

Before doing anything else, why are you using `new[]` instead of `std::string`?  You tagged this as C++, but all of your coding is 'C'.

Comment: I am practicing the use of dynamic char arrays instead of using strings. I define char *question and char *answer in the class definition (not shown) as private variables. Am I not correctly passing information to those variables?

Comment: Those variables are `local`, they are not `private`.  Local variables go up in a puff of smoke when the function exits.  Second, you are not really learning anything with your usage of char arrays in this context.  All you'll learn is how to get frustrated debugging memory corruption issues.  If you really want to learn proper techniques, create a string class and use that instead of std::string.

Comment: question and answer were private within my class definition, I finally realized I was redeclaring them by typing char * before each in the constructor. I use delete in the deconstructer to avoid memory leaks. Thanks for the input!